# Javascript array of arrays that contains obj, take only arrays that contain an obj with a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have array of arrays that contains obj, I should only take arrays that contain an obj with a specific key.

I tried to use a double filter but it doesn't work.

Can you give me some advice?

```js
let result = [
  [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": {
        "id": 1555
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": {
        "id": 5456
      }
    }
  ]
];

const c = result.filter(array => array.filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty('type') === true));

console.log(c);
```

Result:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": {
        "id": 1555
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "type": {
        "id": 5456
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter in your filter function is wrong because you don't want to return a new collection, you want to return a boolean expression. [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) helps and checks if any item in that subarray has this property.

```js
let result = [
  [{
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  [{
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": {
        "id": 1555
      }
    }
  ],
  [{
    "id": 6,
    "type": {
      "id": 5456
    }
  }]
];

const validArrays = result.filter(subArray => subArray.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('type')));

console.log(validArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check whether the length of the return value from the inner array is > 0. Only if the length of the return value from the inner filter is > 0 the outer filter returns true and store it into `validArrays`.

```js
 let result = [[{"id":1},{"id":2}],[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"type":{"id":1555}}],[{"id":6,"type":{"id":5456}}]];

 const validArrays = result.filter(subarray => subarray.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('type') === true).length > 0);
 console.log(validArrays);
```